# angular ng-class from variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

Using Angular I would like to apply class to form field after the form field has been edited. The class name is not stated as string but as variable value which seems to be a problem. Below two snippets of code - working one and failing one.

**A ) This works:**

```
<select ng-model="testModel" 
    ng-options="foo for foo in someList" 
    ng-change="testSwitch = 1" 
    ng-class="{'some-classname' : testSwitch }">
```

**B ) This also works:**

```
<select ng-model="testModel" 
    ng-options="foo for foo in someList" 
    ng-change="testSwitch = 1" 
    ng-class="{testVar}">
```

where:

```
$scope.testVar = 'some-classname';
```

**C ) But this does not:**

In view:

```
<select ng-model="testModel" 
    ng-options="foo for foo in someList" 
    ng-change="testSwitch = 1" 
    ng-class="{testVar : testSwitch }">
```

Does anyone know the reason or other possible solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ternary approach:

```
<select ng-model="testModel" 
    ng-options="foo for foo in someList" 
    ng-change="testSwitch = 1" 
    ng-class="testSwitch? testVar: ''">
```

Comment: Thanks ! that's what I did. Additionally I realized that I don't have to change any variable in on-change thus data in model itself can be used as trigger for change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning the class as a variable, then I think angularJS requires that if you do it that way, you don't do the conditional approach with the : and a boolean.

So, instead of this:

```
    <select ng-model="testModel" 
        ng-options="foo for foo in someList" 
        ng-change="testSwitch = 1" 
        ng-class="{testVar : testSwitch }">
```

Go back to your option **B** and then set the different class name in the controller like this:

```
    $scope.testVar = testSwitch ? 'some-classname' : '';
```

Then it should work just fine.